# IE Javascript issue, reading from localStorage

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage

The following code works fine in Chrome, firefox:

```
if (localStorage.myItem == null) {
    localStorage.myItem = "value";
}

var val = localStorage.myItem;
```

However, when loading up the webpage in IE11, the below error gets thrown:

> Unable to get property 'myItem' of undefined or null reference, Line
>   1, Column 2

(The line where the if conditional is declared)

As far as I'm aware IE8+ supports local storage.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure that your IE8 test platform isn't in IE6 or IE7 compatibility mode?

Comment: Are you running this on http or file protocol?

Comment: @epascarello .....file protocol. Is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, Localstorage is not available on file protocol/

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I seem to be able to get and set using local storage when using running the file protocol in chrome.

Comment: Run a local server! Makes life easier since browsers have different security/limitations on the file protocol.

Comment: here is a python (shell) one liner that pubs the current folder to port 8000: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`